# Should we encourage question voting more?

Tags: discussion, voting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time) on Stack Overflow currently has 16 upvotes. Its single answer has 67 upvotes. This seems lopsided. An answer that's so valuable leads me to think the question is valuable, so why hasn't it been upvoted more?

**Should we encourage question voting more?**

If so:

- Why? What does it do? (I'm not saying these things aren't happening, but how do we know?)

  - Improve search engine results / relevancy?
  - Increase visibility of the question within Stack Exchange?
  - Contribute to the author as an "atta boy?"
- How?

  - I know when you upvote an answer Stack Overflow will remind you to upvote the question. I'm thinking that's not enough. Perhaps it's not shown enough of the time?

If not:

- Then, logically, do we need question voting anyway? I've seen many questions on stackoverflow where the question votes far outreach the sum of answer votes. I assume, in those situations, that many similar question-havers are dropping by, upvoting the question with the thought that "I have that question too. None of these answers satisfy me."

Question voting seems valuable to me, but I'm not sure if I'm basing that on science or a feeling.

Comment: You've never seen the "you haven't voted on a question in a while..." prompt?

Comment: We have a badge that encourages voting on questions

Comment: When an answer gets a lot more votes than the question, it often means that either it was a good answer to a bad question, or a great answer to a mediocre question.

Comment: JayBlanchard, I don't think I've seen that.

juergen d, I think I have that badge. But I didn't know about it until I got it. Maybe the "make sure to upvote the question" popup should mention the badge?

Mysticial, that's quite possible. I often barely read questions when I'm looking for answers. I just jump straight to the answer. I figure if the answer is good, and it's the question that prompted the answer and got me from Google to the answer, then the question was good.

Comment: What on Earth is so great about that question?  He should just have typed the title of his question in Google and would have found the [already existing Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749448/mysql-dump-all-databases-and-create-or-recreate-them-on-import).  These kind of questions belong in the rather awful "Can somebody Google this for me?" category.  They do little but generate duplicates and steer other users the wrong way.  From where they should go, which is of course MySQL's documentation.

Comment: @HansPassant I use google to get to stackoverflow answers, not stackoverflow search. Stackoverflow intended for that to happen from the beginning, because it's a great format for quickly finding answers to specific questions. The question you linked had the same number of upvotes, but its answer had far fewer upvotes. SOMETHING is making the question I linked more useful, based on the number of votes on the answers. What is it?

Comment: @Mysticial who is upvoting the answers? Dedicated stackoverflow-ers browsing the site who just want to reward good answers, or people coming from google for the answer? If it's the former, then your thought makes perfect sense. But if it's the latter, I think the sheer number of answer-upvotes should lead to A) answer-upvoters indicating that they were overall HELPED by the question, as it lead to them getting their answer, and/or B) people improving the question by editing it. B sounds like a good idea to help knowledge on the interwebs.

Comment: Both answers suck, a fairly inevitable side-effect of a sucky question. The more upvoted answer sucks less because it actually recommends reading the MySQL documentation. Prompted to by the comments btw. SO users like these kind of answers because it helps them to stop thinking about the real problem. Q&D fix, it will be somebody else's problem later.  Who will probably end up posting to serverfault.com.  SO legitimizes bad practices.  Wonderful, isn't it?  That's why you want it to get more votes, perhaps?

Comment: I've seen tons of posts where the question itself stinks, but someone was able to make sense of it and post a well written, complete and useful answer to it. A great answer doesn't automatically mean that the question that prompted it is worthy of an upvote, and the fact that you were able to somehow stumble on the good answer in spite of the horrible question doesn't change the quality or value of a poor question. In the link you've cited, the question isn't terribly good (and neither are the answers, frankly). I wouldn't have upvoted anything there personally.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite. As I'm getting more into the community, I suppose it's my responsibility to go read what I should be upvoting. I upvoted both the answer and the question because they "helped" me. I got what I needed. But perhaps I haven't been doing quite the service I intended by being too lenient.

Comment: Following up on Ken White's point, what we should really be encouraging is _improving_ those mediocre questions with excellent answers so that they deserve as many upvotes. The answerers are often in the best position to do this by editing the question to reflect whatever they divined in it that led them to answer.

Comment: "We have a badge that encourages ..." -- ha ha ha. Does anyone really care about badges?

Comment: The particular question cited isn't perhaps the best example.  It is a question that could be trivially answered by referring to the documentation.  I'm not sure if the question and/or the answer merit so many upvotes.

Comment: I have to admit than when I google something I already know the question so I usually don't even read it. When I'm in that mode I just want my answer and I want to get back into coding ASAP before I loose my flow. In that mode I tend to only vote on answers.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think we need to encourage it more because we already encourage it more than enough.

1) The [Electorate Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) already makes it so you are required to be voting on questions.

and

2) Anytime you vote on ***x*** number of answers in a row, a message appears telling you that you haven't voted on questions in a while and that questions need votes too.

Comment: Would you say that answer-upvoters on the linked question knew to THINK about upvoting the question, but decided not to? There are a lot of answer upvotes and views on the question. Shouldn't the question have been down-voted more, or edited for improvement?