# Upvote rewards?

Tags: feature-request, answers, reputation, upvotes

Right now we hand out penalties for the "negative" action of downvoting but there are no direct rewards for the "positive" action of upvoting. Should there be some sort of direct reward to voting up posts and comments?

I say positive and negative purely in the context of reputation points, not in the overall quality of the site. Of course voting questions, answers, and comments both down and up is a good thing to rank the contributions to the community.

The reason I'm asking this is there seems to be a meta-game going on with posts. Several people might come up with excellent answers but they rarely cross-upvote each other. It might be due to the competitive nature of multiple people racing to an answer and not considering the good points in other posts. It might also be that people are seeking the points associated with gaining the accepted answer - to upvote someone else's answer might convince the asker that the one with the most upvotes is the best answer.

If there was a direct reward for promoting good content then perhaps more people would take the time to upvote "competing" answers. Of course, it would have to be limited somehow to prevent people from blindly upvoting to gain points.

Some thoughts:

- One sort of reward might be if you give an upvote you gain a point, up to a certain amount per day.
- Only reward points for contributions to a question if you also have an answer on the question. That way you are not only hoping to get the accepted answer, you are also promoting other people's good answers.
- Should the same go for comments?
- Rewards for someone asking a question and then upvoting comments/answers?
- Should all contributions be rewarded in some way? This is a bit out of the scope of the question but why hand out a reputation loss for downvoting when that person may be helping to improve the quality of the site? Does it prevent trolls more than it prevents useful filtering?

Comment: Wait... "you upvote so you get more rep"... can't you see how broken that'll be? Can you imagine how much fun sock puppets will have with this, and people will start upvoting anything and EVERYTHING just to get points?

Comment: This would create a voting circus

Comment: *Several people might come up with excellent answers but they rarely cross-upvote each other.* There is already [a badge for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship).

Comment: @Patrice That's why there would have to be some controls and limits on it. I agree that simply allowing it to run rampant would be ridiculous. Though that could be done right now with several people creating questions, answering, and accepting them.

Comment: @Colgraff it IS currently done. And.... what's your suggestion to make sure it isn't abused? Without that your FR seems very incomplete and blatantly easy to abuse.

Comment: @BSMP The badge is a great goal but perhaps not quite direct enough to encourage enough people. First, you have to know about it to go for it. Second, gaining reputation might be more tempting than a badge so you'd rather compete for the accepted answer than gain a badge after 100.

Comment: But beyond that, is it really a problem if people don't up vote the other answers? There's a good chance that someone posting an answer to a question with existing answers thinks the existing answers are wrong or lacking in some way. (Not always but then sometimes people do up vote other answers.)

Comment: Yeah - whenever you think up some idea that might improve some aspect of SO, also think about how such a change could be used for fraud, or how it could result in umm... 'instability' :)

Comment: Of course it could be abused and be unstable. I posted a few ideas for limiting that aspect and would welcome more. Overall, I think that encouraging voting is a worthy goal and should be explored whenever possible.

Comment: *up to a certain amount per day.* This wouldn't actually prevent blind up voting, just cap it. *why hand out a reputation loss for downvoting* The down vote cost is to discourage users from down voting competing answers just to make their own answer appear at the top and/or discourage the asker from picking another answer.

Comment: I think that it could lead to something similar like the +2 on accepted edits - There are some bad/minor edits that I believe are the result of the extra 2 points, and I don't want that people will start upvoting bad content just to get rep.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, capping is simply a stop-gap. It wouldn't stop abuse just slow it. On your other point, my thought that giving some reputation (or other reward) for upvoting competing answers would drive the opposite of the downvote penalty: encourage promoting good answers even when they compete.

Comment: It is a proven fact that the answer with the most votes (even by one) is the most likely to receive further votes

Comment: @TinyGiant I think it would be more accurate to say that the answer placed at the top of the list of answers is the most likely to receive further votes.  Usually (but not always) the top answer is the answer with the most votes, making your statement more of an approximate collerary.

Comment: @ColGraff But your proposal doesn't encourage promoting good answers.  It encourages promoting *any* answer, including *bad* answers.

Comment: @Servy That's because I'm not sure how to just promote good answers. I would far prefer to reward upvoting good over bad - and certainly not providing a way to abuse the system without the benefit outweighing the risks.

Comment: @ColGraff Well, let us know when you figure out how to encourage people to reward *good* answers.

Comment: @Servy I think part of it would be to reward on "competing" answers since there is a natural inclination towards not helping the "competition" in pursuit of being the accepted answer. Since you're helping the "competition" a reward for being altruistic seems in-line. Perhaps further limit it by only rewarding if you have a positive answer in the first place so someone couldn't post a bad answer and gain rep by upvoting others.

Comment: @ColGraff But that's *even worse*. You're incentivised much more heavily to upvote a competing answer that's *much worse* than yours, because it won't be able to compete with yours even with your upvote, whereas you're *disincentive* from upvoting other good answers that are providing meaningful competition for it, making it harder for your answer to get attention. It also incentivises people to post a mediocre answer (something not actually good, but not bad enough to get downvotes) on a question with a ton of other answers (i.e. popular questions with dozens of answers), which isn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy Excellent points. This is exactly why I was hoping to drive a conversation about the idea. To see the pitfalls and try to find new ideas to encourage upvoting without introducing an unacceptable level of exploits.

Comment: @Servy I was mainly referring to the point when the question is most active, where there usually is not an accepted answer yet, in which case there is a tendency toward upvoting the highest voted answer and ignoring other answers. Of course this is true even after the question becomes inactive, in which case it will go to whatever answer is at the top of the list. Of course that is nothing close to a proven fact, I meant that part in jest.

Comment: The point being that users may not be not-upvoting competing answers solely because of the accept mark, but rather because they want to be at the top of the pile because the post at the top of the pile is the most likely to get the upvotes. The 15 rep from an accept is meaningless in comparison to the upvotes.

Comment: what we really need is probably [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/165773)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269334/should-we-encourage-question-voting-more

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the link. I looked for related questions and didn't come across that one. Interesting reading.

Comment: I don't have time to upvote competing answers. 

While they're typing their answer to a trivial, duplicate question, I'm busy Googling a duplicate I'm certain exists. This happens for 9 out of 10 questions.

Comment: In just 73 days you can gain the privilege of voting to close and open question and 498 days to become a trusted user just from voting! (assuming 1 rep from each upvote)

Answer (score 35):

So what, you want a +1 every time you upvote something? 40 rep per day for voting?

**This would be detrimental to the site.**

First off, let's look at the obvious result. Everyone wants to get their guaranteed 40 reputation for the day, so they dole out 40 upvotes. It probably (hopefully, okay let's be honest at some point it no longer will) go towards deserving posts. This results in 0 downvotes. The most obvious problem to this suggestion is that no one downvotes any more. This means that question bans no longer work as effectively; the roomba can no longer work; quality is never balanced against dissent.

That would just be the first aspect of it. Next, as indicated above, once users ran out of votes for exceptional posts, since they are essentially forced into voting 40 times per day, they will begin to branch out to ever more questionable content to upvote. This will degrade the balance of voting on the site for which content is truly noteworthy, as the new swath of upvoting will drown out years of balanced voting.

Further, aside from the many users upvoting at unprecedented levels, there would still be users trying to stem the tide, voting as they should. These users will face an exponential amount of fatigue from attempting to combat rogue upvoting. They will burn out.

This would cause question quality to drop dramatically, overall content to suffer due to the increase of material being retained which should not have, and users focused on maintaining site quality to fatigue or just burn out.

While this question is a valid feature request, it is also a very harmful thing to suggest.

Comment: No, as I said in my question there wouldn't be a +1 for every vote. It would be limited in several ways. First of all, only a few gains a day - maybe 5 or 10, maybe less. Second, perhaps limit it to only "competing" answers or on questions you have contributed to. Third, I posted the question in order to elicit ideas on other limitations that could curb abuses. I'm sure that there are ways to encourage upvoting while limiting the negative consequences, if there was a good discussion on it.

Comment: To your points, first, if there was a daily cap, it would just cause this situation to play out slightly slower - but it would still happen; second, limiting it to competing answers would present the same problem albeit in a narrower scope; third, start a discussion on an issue you observe. Requesting a feature titled "upvote rewards" which explicitly outlines rewarding upvotes with reputation is completely different than a discussion about how to reward answerers. There is also the sportsmanship badge for upvoting competing answers.

Comment: Should I remove the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag? I thought it was relevant but if it clouds the discussion then I'll remove it.

Comment: @ColGraff Your question is requesting a feature, so it should obviously be tagged appropriately.  If you were to ask a question that wasn't actually requesting a feature, and was doing something else, then perhaps another tag would apply.  Changing your question, after you've asked it, to ask something completely different isn't appropriate, so changing your question now to be a support question or a bug report or anything else wouldn't be appropriate; if you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 15):

Upvoting upvotable content is its own reward. It makes good content more prominent on the site, thus improving both the utility of the good content and the site as a whole.

What more reason would you need?

Comment: I don't personally need any more reason, I think that upvoting is a good thing to do. It improves the community and makes good content easier to find. However, I've seen many instances where questions have several decent answers with no upvotes. You'd expect that some of the people answering and commenting would take the time to look at and vote on the other content but they obviously don't. It made me wonder if there was some gaming going on where people didn't vote on other content so it wouldn't rise above their own. Then I wondered if there were ways to change this. So, here we are!